# Return a string from JSON through Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm looking to return the skill below from a variable:

```
const skillsData = [
  { name: "React", value: 390 },
  { name: "CSS", value: 1200 },
  { name: "JavsScript", value: 540 },
  { name: "HTML", value: 1900 },
  { name: "CSS", value: 1278 },
];
```

Within a function, I am using the following:

```
let maxSkills = Math.max.apply(Math, skillsData.map(function(o) { return o.value; }))
```

This will obviously return a value, which has worked for one case, however what is the correct way to return the following 'name' key on the basis?

Furthermore, what would be a function to sort these in ascending value, so that you return HTML as the last in JSON?

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you trying to get the name property of the object with the highest value property or sort them by value property?

Comment: Hi about14sheep, I'm actually trying to do both. I would like to sort them by value property in the json, but I would also like to return the highest 'name' key on the basis of the value and store it in a variable as above.

Comment: If you sort it in either direction, `HTML` would be neither last nor first.

Comment: you can use [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value) to figure out how to sort the array based on a property. Then just have a variable set to the first index of that array to isolate the maximum

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array by using the `sort` method.

This will produce the array sorted in descending order:

```js
skillsData.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
```

and ascending order:

```js
skillsData.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value)
```

The following code will print the `.name` value of the first element in the sorted array. The first element holds the maximum `value`, as `sortedSkillsData` is in descending order.

```js
const skillsData = [
  { name: "React", value: 390 },
  { name: "CSS", value: 1200 },
  { name: "JavsScript", value: 540 },
  { name: "HTML", value: 1900 },
  { name: "CSS", value: 1278 },
];

let sortedSkillsData = skillsData.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
let maxSkills = sortedSkillsData[0].name;
console.log(maxSkills);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sort` method and sort in ascending order and then get the last element and then property `name` from that.

```js
const skillsData = [
  { name: "React", value: 390 },
  { name: "CSS", value: 1200 },
  { name: "JavsScript", value: 540 },
  { name: "HTML", value: 1900 },
  { name: "CSS", value: 1278 },
];

const maxSkills = skillsData.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value).slice(-1)[0].name
console.log(maxSkills)
```